# PL/SQL Handle Not Predefined Exceptions

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do you handle PL/SQL errors that are not predefined?

Predefined exceptions are the following:

- ACCESS_INTO_NULL
- CASE_NOT_FOUND
- COLLECTION_IS_NULL
- CURSOR_ALREADY_OPENED
- DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
- INVALID_CURSOR
- INVALID_NUMBER
- NO_DATA_FOUND
- PROGRAM_ERROR
- ROWTYPE_MISMATCH
- STORAGE_ERROR
- SUBSCRIPT_BEYOND_COUNT
- SUBSCRIPT_OUTSIDE_LIMIT
- SYS_INVALID_ROWID
- TOO_MANY_ROWS
- VALUE_ERROR
- ZERO_DIVIDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler that looks at the `SQLCODE`.  But you're generally better off defining an exception that you can handle.  That is going to lead to cleaner code, it lets you map your exception name to a number just once, and makes user-defined exceptions look just like predefined exceptions.

```
declare 
  column_already_indexed exception;
  pragma exception_init( column_already_indexed, -1408 );
begin
  call_procedure;
exception
  when column_already_indexed
  then
    null;
    -- Do something with the exception
end;
```

Comment: I answered with how I eventually figured out how to do it but your approach is definitely cleaner.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can handle errors outside of the predefined with the following:

```
BEGIN
   buggyprocedure; --Call to a procedure that can throw exceptions
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  --Catch predefined exception
      NULL; --Ignore no_data_found
   WHEN OTHERS THEN  --Catch all other exceptions
      IF SQLCODE = -1408 THEN  --Catch error -1408
          NULL; --Ignore this exception
      ELSEIF SQLCODE = -955 THEN --Catch error -955
          anotherprocedure; --Call a different procedure
      ELSE
          RAISE; --Re-raise exception that we are not handling
      END IF;
END;
```

You basically catch all other exceptions, then use `if` and `else` statements to check if the `SQLCODE` returned is one you are expecting and want to handle.